# Implementing foldRight using Custom Operator

Tags: scala

Continuing to work on [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/) exercises, I'm working on implementing `foldRight` on an `IndexedSeq` type.

Since foldRight will evaluate with `right associativity`, I created the following operator for pattern matching.

```
object :++ {
  def unapply[T](s: Seq[T]) = s.lastOption.map(last => 
                                                  (last, s.take(s.length - 1)))
}
```

And then implemented as so:

```
object IndexedSeqFoldable extends Foldable[IndexedSeq] {
  override def foldRight[A, B](as: IndexedSeq[A])(z: B)(f: (A, B) => B): B = {
    def go(bs: Seq[A], acc: B): B = bs match {
        case x :++ xs => go(xs, f(x, acc)) 
        case _ => acc
    }
    go(as, z)
  }
```

Ignoring the fact that `foldRight` can be written with `foldLeft`, how does my approach hold up?

Comment: in terms of performance, readability or what is your criteria?

Comment: In terms of idiomatic Scala